# "No bootable device" error after deleting a partition

Tags: boot, partition, reboot

I have a laptop on which I have an installation of Zorin OS (It is not a Dual-Boot), today I was trying to delete a partition from a USB disk that I have, the disk manager tool that Zorin has installed by default is the same than Ubuntu (I think it's name is Disks), in which the main hard drive can be accessed, I got confused about the disk, and accidentally deleted a partition (unknown to me) from my main hard drive. When I realized it, I thought that something on the computer would crash right away but nothing happened, when I rebooted the computer, I got the following error "No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key", I think what I deleted it was the boot partition because I didn't get any error when deleting it and the error comes out when starting the computer. I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have deleted the boot partition, there there is nothing much you can do. But go for a fresh installation again.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. Can i still backup my data from a Live Boot @Praveen Kumar-M?